# How to validate String to Calendar input?

Tags: java, string, validation, calendar

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow. I would need some help in validation of user input from String to Calendar.

For example, if a user enters something such as "1" or "hi". How cann I validate and prompt an error message for the user to type in the DDMMYYYY format (Which is something like 04 02 2015)

```
System.out.print("Enter Date (DD MM YYYY): ");
          input.nextLine();
          String pickUpDate = input.nextLine();
          Calendar pd = stringToCalendarConverter(pickUpDate);

public static Calendar stringToCalendarConverter(String stringToCal) //Converts String to Calendar
{
   try 
   {
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy"); 
     Date date = df.parse(stringToCal);
     Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
     calendar.setTime(date);  
     return calendar;
  }
  catch (ParseException n) 
  {
     return null;
  }
```

}

Comment: **Don't** edit the question title or content to mark it solved. Simply marking the accepted question is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`DateFormat.setLenient(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) which says (in part) *with strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.*  Something like,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy"); 
df.setLenient(false);
```

Then to call your method in a loop (to re-prompt for the date on `null`)

```
Calendar pd = null;
while (pd == null) {
    System.out.print("Enter Date (DD MM YYYY): ");
    input.nextLine();
    String pickUpDate = input.nextLine();
    pd = stringToCalendarConverter(pickUpDate);
}
```

Comment: It still doesnt work. When i input "1" into the date. The program crashes.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy"); 
     df.setLenient(false);
     Date date = df.parse(stringToCal);
     Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
     calendar.setTime(date);  
     return calendar;

Comment: It did work. Your method returns `null` when the date entered is invalid (that's what you did in the `Exception` handler, now that it isn't in lenient mode you get an `Exception`). Add a check in `main()` before using the returned date.

Comment: Ahh i see!  But how do i prompt the user to retype the date? Sorry i'm not that good in java, hope you could help me out more! Thank you!

Comment: @Dracogon121 Easiest way, use a loop. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void dateConversion() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date (DD MM YYYY): ");

    String pickUpDate = input.nextLine();        
    stringToCalendarConverter(pickUpDate);
}

public static void stringToCalendarConverter(String stringToCal) //Converts String to Calendar
{
    Calendar calendar = null;
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
        df.setLenient(true);
        Date date = df.parse(stringToCal);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);

    } catch (ParseException n) {    // If the user entered incorrect format, it will be catch here.
        System.out.println("Invalid date format, pls try again.");
        dateConversion();           // Prompt the user to enter valid date.
    } finally{
        if(calendar != null){   
            showActualDate(calendar);
        }
    }
}

private static void showActualDate(Calendar cal){
    System.out.println("Entered ::::" +cal.getTime().toString());
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident that OP does not want a lenient `DateFormat`.